# Histogram is displaying nothing in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I have tried so many times, but my histogram id not displaying the graph and only displaying the axis line. Here is the code i am using to plot histogram. Please help!

```
%matplotlib inline
bins = np.linspace(0, 2, 40)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.hist(x_input, bins, alpha=0.5, histtype='bar')
plt.legend(['Red', 'Blue','Green'])
plt.axis([1,500,0,300])
plt.show()
```

Comment: what x_input contains? Can you give some range values of the input?

Comment: Try the same code removing `plt.axis([1,500,0,300])`

Answer (score 0):

When trying your code, the problems comes from `plt.axis([1,500,0,300])`.

What are the values in `x_input` ?

Maybe changing the parameters of `linspace` can solve your problem too.
Because you have 40 bins between 0 and 2, but your axis go to 500.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your **bins**. Following code gave mi right plot

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
  x_input=[[10,20,30,40,50,60],[10,20,30,40,50,60],[10,20,30,40,50,60]]
  bins = np.linspace(0, 2, 40)
  plt.hist(x_input,alpha=0.9)
  plt.legend(['Red', 'Blue','Green'])
  plt.axis([1,20,0,20])
  plt.show()
```

If problem does not persist share data with your are trying to plot